# VBA Open a file with changing title

Tags: vba, excel

I need to to open a file using VBA that has a changing title. The file name is called Membership_Sales_Figures_for_14082017-20082017_104942.xls. 
My code is producing an error where it can't find the file. It's referring to the file as Weekly Control\Membership.xls

```
Sub Test()



Const fpath As String = "Weekly Control\Membership\"
Dim fname As String
Dim lname As String

' Below gives you the Monday of the week
fname = Format(Date - (Weekday(Date) + 6) + 1, "ddmmyyyy")
lname = Format(Date - (Weekday(Date)) + 1, "ddmmyyyy")
fname = "Membership_Sales_Figures_for_" & fname & "-" & lname & "*" & ".xls"
fname = fpath & fname
fname = fpath & Dir(fname)




Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fname)
If wb Is Nothing Then MsgBox "File does not exist": Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `dir(fname)` to find a file that matches your expression. Note that it returns the first found file.

```
fname = "Membership_Sales_Figures_for_" & fname & "-" & lname & "*" & ".xls" 
fname = fpath & fname
fname = fpath & dir(fname)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be correct. However I am getting a message saying the file can't be found. In the error message the filename appears to be the exact same as the file on the drive?

Comment: That appears to be a different issue. Try hardcoding the filename. Does it work then?

Comment: No I get the same message. The code I posted was working so it seems to be linked to the dir ?

Comment: Edited it to add the path twice

Comment: Apologies @Erik, code seems to have stopped working ? It's now saying it can't find the file at Weekly Control\Membership\.xls . I have updated my question with the script I am now running.

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print fname` between `fname = fpath & fname` and 
`fname = fpath & dir(fname)`?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have tried that but am getting the same error message about not being able to find the file?

Comment: Eh... A `debug.print` statement gives a message in the immediate window, please give me what it printed. It fixes nothing.

Comment: Apologies, view wasn't setup correctly. The debug.print is showing Weekly Control\Membership\Membership_Sales_Figures_for_14082017-20082017*.xls

Comment: And does a file that fit that pattern exist?

Comment: Yes the file is called Membership_Sales_Figures_for_14082017-20082017_104942.xls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152544/discussion-between-erik-von-asmuth-and-e-mcandrew).

Comment: Can you please explain what each line does? Thanks

Comment: There really only is one relevant line changed, the bottom one. I explained that at the top. I'm not going to explain localized code that isn't mine.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this file.
 "Membership_Sales_Figures_for_14082017-20082017_104942.xls"

But your code adds an "*" at the end of the file.

```
fname = "Membership_Sales_Figures_for_" & fname & "-" & lname & "*" & ".xls"
```

Remove the `& "*"`